# How do I get my Python Flask app on an Ubuntu ec2 to connect with a MySQL db with RDS?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am attempting to get my app to connect to my database on an RDS, also I am using NGINX. When connecting to the ec2 remotely using a terminal I can connect to the database there fine. It is on the public-facing side where the error exists. I followed a guide given to me by a coding school step by step. The initial login/registration page will load, but if I try to create an account or login error I get a 500 Internal service error.
[image: 500 Error]

I set up my security group correctly as far as inbound rules go. Are there any outbound rules I need on the ec2 for it to be able to contact the RDS from the public ip?

Thank you

Note: I am not getting graded on this at this point, I already finished the Python stack, this is just something I still want to figure out. I don't like leaving something unfinished. I've taken the time and read many articles, watched videos, gone through AWS documentation and still cannot figure the issue out.

Comment: Any time "internal server" error happens there will be logs on your application. can you please add the logs in the question?

Comment: Have you tried to use SqlAlchemy? Check this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-python-sqlalchemy-orm-to-interact-with-an-amazon-aurora-database-from-a-serverless-application/

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, had to go to the hospital Wednesday for something with my shoulders. @HosseinHeydari Where would I find those logs? I've looked through most the stuff available to me and I can't seem to find them.

Comment: @GeorgeEfthymiou I am looking into SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I found the following in a log on cloud trails: "AccessDeniedAccess Denied="
The issue doesn't exist until a post request is made to the database.

Comment: I believe I had the credentials wrong in the mysqlconnection.py file; I just reset the password for my RDS, fixed something with the security group, and am waiting for the RDS to update.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, the issue turned out to be that the database was not located on RDS, it was on the ec2 along with the flask app. I just needed to go into the mysqlconnection.py file and change the host to 'localhost', username to 'root', and the password.

Thanks